# I need help truncating characters beyond 40 in the one column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My code fails to truncate anything beyond 40 characters when i run it. Any suggestions on what line I can use. The code is an xlam. I am trying to truncate anything in column G  I tried to put in formula left(F2, 40). Maybe i am using a wrong formula? or there is another way to fix it. Please let me know.  Here is the Code I have so far:

```
 Option Explicit


    Private Sub ProcessReport()       
       
       Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
       Dim oXLAM As Excel.Workbook       
       Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet        
       
       Set oWB = ActiveWorkbook
       
       Set oWS = ActiveSheet
       
       Set oXLAM = Workbooks("NRPPosPay.xlam")
       
       Call formatcols  
    End Sub

    Sub formatcols()
          Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet
          Dim LastPopulatedRow As Long
          LastPopulatedRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Delete Colums
        Columns("F:H").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    'Move Colums
        Columns("E:E").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns("B:B").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        
        Columns("G:G").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns("C:C").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        
        Columns("G:G").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns("C:C").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        
        Columns("E:E").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns("D:D").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        
        Columns("G:G").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns("E:E").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        
        Columns("G:G").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns("F:F").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        
        
    'Replace in Colums
       Range("G:G").Replace What:=",", Replacement:=" "
       Range("C:C").Replace What:="-", Replacement:=" "
       Range("E:E").Replace What:="OCK", Replacement:="IS"
       Range("E:E").Replace What:="VCK", Replacement:="CN"
       
    'Formula in Columns
      Range("G2").Formula = "=left(G2, 40)"
      Range("G2: " & "G" & LastPopulatedRow).FillDown
          
    'Copy and Paste
       Range("G:G").Copy
       Range("F:F").PasteSpecial _
       Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationDivide
      
       
     'Delete Column
      Columns("G:G").Select
      Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    'Replace
       Range("F:F").Replace What:=",", Replacement:=" "
       
     
    'Format columns
       Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "0"
       Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "0"
       Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "#.00"
       Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "mddyyyy"
       
       
    ' Delete Header row
    
       Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    End Sub
    
    Sub ProcessPos(control As IRibbonControl)
        Call ProcessReport
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you limit the code to the relevant portion? We don't need to see the whole sub just the problem part with relevant variables. Also, what happens when you try to use the `LEFT` formula? Are you getting error, unexpected output, etc.

Comment: @urdearboy. When i use LEFT formula it looks like it doesn't work. The code doesn't even recognize that line

Comment: Oh you have a circular reference. In cell G2 you are trying to put `LEFT(G2, 40)`. If you do this on the sheet you will see it produces a error. The code should still drop in the formula so you have another error somewhere else I'm guessing

Comment: Try `Range("G2").Value = Mid(Range("G2"), 1, 40)` instead

Comment: Isn't this circular: `  Range("G2").Formula = "=left(G2, 40)" `?

Comment: I think you meant to write `Range("G2").Formula = Left(Range("G2"), 40)` which would use the VBA function [Left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function) to truncate the text as you described. But then you can't use `.FillDown`. You would need to iterate through the range in VBA with a loop.

Comment: Side Note: Anytime you use `Thing.Select -> Selection.Stuff` Just get rid of select... its not doing anything helpful and just causes screen jittering as it highlights ranges in rapid succession. Rewrite all of that to a single line like `Thing.Stuff`

Comment: @urdearboy` I tried Range("G2").Value = Mid(Range("G2"), 1, 40) and it's working perfectly. How can i make sure i do it for all the rows in G

Answer (score 3):

Leaving all other changes that you can do to improve the code you should replace this line

```
Range("G2").Formula = "=left(G2, 40)"
```

with this one:

```
Range("G2").Value = Left(Range("G2").Value, 40)
```

This would make your code do what you desire for cell G2 now you can use loop to do this for all cells.

Comment: As  @urdearboy said above - this is still a circular reference

Comment: @dbmitch No, this is not circular. VBA evaluates the expression first, which means it puts the current value of Range("G2").Value into the function `Left`. Then it takes the returned value from that function and applies it to the `Let` statement which would be Range("G2")'s `.Value` property. So after VBA breaks things down you end up with `Let .Value = ReturnedValue` which is not circular at all.